# NTFS Share vs. NFS Datastore on VMware 5.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs, ntfs, windows-server-2012-r2, datastore

I am currently using Physical Server 2012R2 of 10TB RAID5 mapped as a NTFS share to the Virtual Machine, which is a Camera Server 2012R2 hosted on VMware 5.5.
Storage Server is used only for all video backup files.

Is it advisable to create a NFS share (As a NFS roll) on Physical Server 2012R2 of 10TB RAID5 and add it as a Datastore on the VMware 5.5 host?

I am new to the VMware environment and want to know if that is the right practice, any pros and cons?

Comment: What is the problem with the current setup?

Comment: Current setup has no issues but changing setup to NFS Datastore make sense in data management, easy backups and robust environment?

Comment: Naw, it doesn't make sense to use NFS if the consumer of the data is a Windows server.